# How to shuffle results in Lighthouse GraphQL (order by random)?

Tags: graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I see [docs for `@orderBy`](https://lighthouse-php.com/4.12/api-reference/directives.html#orderby) but am curious how I could sort my Lighthouse GraphQL results randomly, kind of like `inRandomOrder` in [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset):

```
$randomUser = DB::table('users')
            ->inRandomOrder()
            ->first();
```

Or like `RAND()` in MySQL:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM mytable
ORDER BY RAND();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it is not possible out of the box with lighthouse since there is no `RAND` SortOrder Enum.

You could use a scope for that.

Suppose you want to grab randomly some users from your table. Create a scope in you user query in your `schema.graphql`

```
type Query {
    posts(
        random: Boolean @scope(name: "random")
    ): [User!]!
}
```

Create the scope in your `App\User.php`:

```php
// ...

/**
 * Shuffles the users randomly
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
 public function scopeRandom($query) {
    return $query->inRandomOrder();
 }

// ...
```

Utilize the scope in your query:

```
{
  users(random: true) 
  {
    id,
    email,
    username
  }
}
```

This is fine for small datasets but keep in mind that for larger datasets this could be a possible performance bottleneck.

Comment: This worked! I really appreciate it. Now I just need to find a way to have my `gql` include its `orderBy` object variable (which has keys `field` and `order`) only when the `random` variable is false.